# If I play a Priest with sewers, do I get + $2 for trashing the card with sewers?

Tags: dominion, dominion-renaissance

Priest reads:

> +$2. Trash a card from your hand. For the rest of this turn, when you trash a card, +$2.

Sewers reads:

> When you trash a card other than from this, you may trash a card from your hand.

**When you play a Priest, and then you trash a card with Sewers, do you get + $2?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not.

The "For the rest of this turn" bit of Priest's instructions will have not happened yet by the time you trash your Sewers card. It would play out like this.

- Play Priest

  - Get +$2
  - Trash a card from your hand

    - Sewers triggers, so you trash a card from your hand
  - For the rest of this turn, when you trash a card, +$2

This was confirmed by Donald X in a post [here](http://forum.dominionstrategy.com/index.php?topic=19025.msg771906#msg771906):

> You play Priest. You get +$2. You trash a card. Sewers triggers and you trash a second card. Now Priest's "this turn when you trash +$2" becomes active. It wasn't active during either card trash.